# Fire off a function as an HTML5 video starts playing?

Tags: jquery, html5-video, jwplayer

I'm trying to fire off a function as an HTML5 `<video>` comes into existence (via [JWPlayer](http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/)) and starts playing (or starts getting media data or buffering). Here's what I've got:

```
$('video').live('playing', function() {
    alert('Playing!');
});
```

I'm using jQuery [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) to listen for the creation of the `<video>` element... on an iPad, where there's no Flash, JWPlayer will create and insert a standard `<video>` block where the Flash video player would normally be. The `'playing'` piece is the event that should trigger the function according to this list of media events:
http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#mediaevents

Clearly, I'm doing this wrong. But what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The 'playing' event won't fire until the video begins to play. If that's the event you want to use, try:

```
var vid = $('video')[0];
$(vid).live('playing', function() {
    alert('Playing!');
});
```

You may also be interested in the [loadedmetadata](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/consistent-event-firing-with-html5-video/) event. That fires once the video's meta data has loaded (things like the video duration, etc.).

```
var vid = $('video')[0];
$(vid).on('loadedmetadata', function() {
    alert(vid.duration);
});
```